# Why does my value keep returning as "NaN"?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, local-storage

[Here](http://jsbin.com/taguda/2) is the link to the jsbin.

I was almost finished with my project (I thought I was) and then I tested it out. It is supposed to add buttons with the chosen title of the task and the number of points it awards. Every time the button is clicked the points would be added on to the "Points" section and every 500 points my "Level" would increase.

Upon finishing it, it worked. Then I went to clear the localStorage since that's what I used to save the information, but I wanted to start over. When I did that, the 'Points' section, or 'results' value, keeps returning as "NaN". The code is exactly the same as it was when it worked. Can someone please tell me how to fix this problem, thank you in advance.

Here is the code. (Used bootstrap for CSS)

HTML

```
<center>

  <br>
   <h2> Add task </h2>

  <div class='well' style='width:500px' id="addc"> 
    <div id="addc">
    <input class='form-control' style='width:450px' id="btnName" type="text" placeholder="New Task" /><br>
    <input class='form-control' style='width:450px' id="btnPoints" type="text" placeholder="Points" /><br>

      <button id="addBtn">Add</button>

      </div> </div>

<div class='well' style='width:230px' id="container">

</div>

  <hr style="width:400px;">

  <h3>Points </h3>
<div id="result">0</div>

</div>



<hr style="width:400px;">

<div  style="width:400px;">
  <h3>Level 
  <p id='lvl'>0</p>

</div>

<hr style="width:400px;">


</center>
```

JavaScript

```
var res = document.getElementById('result');
res.innerText = localStorage.getItem('myResult');

var level = document.getElementById('lvl');
level.textContent = localStorage.getItem('myLevel');


var btns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
for(var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
    btns[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        addToResult(this.getAttribute('data-points'));
        this.parentNode.removeChild(this.nextElementSibling);
        this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
    });
}
var addBtn = document.getElementById('addBtn');
addBtn.className = "btn btn-default";
addBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var container = document.getElementById('container');
    var btnName = document.getElementById('btnName').value;
    var btnPoints = parseInt(document.getElementById('btnPoints').value);
    if(!btnName)
        btnName = "Button ?";
    if(!btnPoints)
        btnPoints = 50;
    var newBtn = document.createElement('button');
    var newPnt = document.createElement('span');
    newBtn.className = 'btn btn-danger';
    newBtn.innerText = btnName;
    newBtn.setAttribute('data-points', btnPoints);
    newBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
        addToResult(this.getAttribute('data-points'));
        this.parentNode.removeChild(this.nextElementSibling);
        this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
    });
    newPnt.className = 'label';
    newPnt.innerText = "+" + btnPoints;
    container.appendChild(newBtn);
    container.appendChild(newPnt);
});




function addToResult(pts) {
    var result = document.getElementById('result');
    result.innerText = parseInt(result.innerText) + parseInt(pts);
    var lvl = 0;
    var a = 100;

    while (result.innerText > 5*a) {
      lvl+=1;
      a+=100;
    }
  document.getElementById('lvl').innerText = lvl;

   var res = document.getElementById('result');
  localStorage.setItem("myResult", res.innerText);

  var level = document.getElementById('lvl');
  localStorage.setItem("myLevel", level.textContent);


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were parsing `result.innerText` as a number, but its value, initially, was actually either `NaN` or nothing, both which end up being `NaN`. One fix is to just check if it parsed to a number, and if it didn't, fall back to `0`.

I just basically changed that and removed some `getElementById`s that, in my opinion, were redundant, check the `addToResult` function:

http://jsfiddle.net/owc26a0p/1/

```
function addToResult(pts) {
    // NaN is falsy, so you can just use || to make a fallback to 0
    var result = parseInt(resDiv.innerText, 10) || 0,
        lvl = 0,
        a = 100;
    result = result + parseInt(pts, 10) || 0;
    while (result > 5 * a) {
        lvl += 1;
        a += 100;
    }
    resDiv.innerText = result;
    levelDiv.innerText = lvl;
    localStorage.setItem("myResult", result);
    localStorage.setItem("myLevel", levelDiv.textContent);

}
```

I ended up using jsFiddle since I couldn't always get jsBin to save my changes. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you so much, I really had no idea what I had to do to make it work. Thank you

Comment: I was wondering if you could further help me with some of the things I'm trying to do, only if you're not too busy. It seems what you know could be really beneficial to the last part of my project. Thank you anyway :)

Comment: Yeah sure, I can try to help, what do you need to do?

Comment: Thank you. I've tried many times but I just can't seem to figure it out. There are two things I've been having problems with. The first is I'd really like for the user, after they put the "task" title and the amount of points in, to click on one of the "spans" or subjects, and when they click "add", the button created is the same colour as it's corresponding subject. Also I tried to make it so that when you click one of the tasks, after you've completed them, on the far-right div, for an alert to come up for each task completed, "You have just complete *task*".Do you think you can help me out?

Comment: This is the updated link to the current project..  http://output.jsbin.com/taguda

This is the code
https://jsfiddle.net/5c3ptccm/

Comment: Also, would it be possible to store the created buttons in localStorage too? I have no idea how to do so.

Comment: May I ask from where did you learn javascript? I'm very interested, would love to be able to do all this stuff without needing help haha, thanks again.

Comment: I think I get what you want to do. I'll take a look at it tomorrow, and see what I can do, is that okay? It's just that I have some stuff I've gotta finish at the moment (that I should've finished long ago). And I guess you really want to finish this now... Well, I'm still learning JavaScript, so, for instance, I don't know what the best way for storing the buttons would be, but I'm thinking maybe you should store the properties of those buttons, in a way that you can rebuild them when you want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77427/discussion-between-alfonso-garnett-and-samir-chahine).